# Too much connections open when execute a query

Tags: java, postgresql

I have my app deployed on Heroku where I can see opened connections. The problem is when I execute some queries (for example simple login) then numbers of connections open and I don't know why. Currently there are 18 connections but it should be just a few. It is strange because I always close them in my code. For example it leaps from 1 to 17 connections even when I try to check if login data is corrrect. Here it is:

my dataSource bean:

```
    @Bean
public DataSource dataSource() throws URISyntaxException {
    URI dbUri = new URI("postgres://abc:def:1234/ghi");

    String username = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[0];
    String password = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[1];
    String dbUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://" + dbUri.getHost() + ':' + dbUri.getPort() + dbUri.getPath();

    DataSourceBuilder basicDataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    basicDataSource.url(dbUrl);
    basicDataSource.username(username);
    basicDataSource.password(password);

    return basicDataSource.build();
}
```

login()

```
    @GetMapping("/login" )
public boolean login(@RequestParam String login, @RequestParam String pass, HttpServletRequest request) throws SQLException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    String maxOnline = "0";
    int onlineNow;

    boolean check =  usersDao.userExists(login,pass, dataSource.getConnection());
    if(check) {
        usersDao.setOnline(session.getId(), login, pass, dataSource.getConnection());

        maxOnline = serverPropsDao.getPropValue("max_online", dataSource.getConnection());
        onlineNow = usersDao.usersOnline(dataSource.getConnection()).size();

        if (Integer.parseInt(maxOnline) < onlineNow)
            serverPropsDao.setPropValue("max_online", String.valueOf(onlineNow), dataSource.getConnection());

    }
    return check;
}
```

userExists()

```
public boolean userExists(String name, String pass, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
boolean result = false;
    PreparedStatement ps;
    try {
        ps = connection.prepareStatement("select count(*) as total from users where name='" + name + "' and pass='" + pass + "'");
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next())
            result = rs.getInt("total") > 0;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    connection.close();
    return result;
}
```

setOnline()

```
public void setOnline(String sessionId, String name, String pass, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement ps;
    try {
        ps = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE users SET session_id ='" + sessionId + "' WHERE name='" + name + "' and pass='" + pass + "'");
        ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    connection.close();
}
```

getPropValue()

```
    public String getPropValue(String prop, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    String value="";
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    try {
        stmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT value FROM server_props where prop='"+prop+"'");
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            value = rs.getString(1);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        return e.getMessage();
    }
    connection.close();
    return value;
}
```

usersOnline()

```
    public List<User> usersOnline(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
    PreparedStatement ps;
    try {
        ps = connection.prepareStatement("select * from users where session_id != 'offline'");
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            users.add(new User(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(6)));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    connection.close();
    return users;
}
```

setPropValue()

```
    public String setPropValue(String prop, String value, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    String result="ok";
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    try {
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE server_props SET value ='"+value+"' WHERE prop='"+prop+"'");
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        result = e.getMessage();
    }
    connection.close();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You don't show how your dataSource is configured. perhaps it is a pool and is preferring to reopen connections rather than reuse them. Also any uncaught exception will result in a connection being leaked, you should do your close in a finally clause (or use try with resources)

Comment: That data source will be a connection pool, the exact type will depend what spring finds on the class path. So that is your explanation.

Comment: So what can I change to make it proper?

Comment: You need to understand how your connection pool is configured and set the maximum number of connections to a figure you are happy with. As we don't know which connection pool you are using we can't tell you exactly how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be able to tell whether its your own code getting all those connections if you re-used same connection of one call to `dataSource.getConnection()`  in try-with-resources (as it is AutoCloseable) and got rid of all calls to `connection.close();` :

```
try(Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection())
{
    boolean check =  usersDao.userExists(login,pass, conn);
    if(check) {
        usersDao.setOnline(session.getId(), login, pass, conn);

        maxOnline = serverPropsDao.getPropValue("max_online", conn);
        onlineNow = usersDao.usersOnline(conn).size();

        if (Integer.parseInt(maxOnline) < onlineNow)
            serverPropsDao.setPropValue("max_online", String.valueOf(onlineNow), conn);

    }
}
```

Comment: Also you might want to check whether your DataSource sets up an initial pool size which might also be cause of those extra connections when you get the first one

Comment: "Also you might want to check whether your DataSource sets up an initial pool size which might also be cause of those extra connections when you get the first one" How to do this? I used your solution and now this method returns "For input string: Connection is closed."

Comment: Did you remove all calls to `connection.close()` in each of the methods as they would close `conn` being passed onto the next call made? Please add the stack trace if that doesn't help. Many DataSource implementations support initial-size=NN setting but you'd need to lookup the documentation from the DS vendor to check the exact property setting to add (that is assuming it is supported), it may be set to 17/18 for your application server.

Comment: I modified a bit your code. I added Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection() in constructor and it almost works as I expect. It's 8 connections but it's always better than 18.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to put connection.close() in your finally statement

```
try {
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE server_props SET value ='"+value+"' WHERE prop='"+prop+"'");
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
}catch ... {
        e.printStackTrace();
        result = e.getMessage();
} finally {
      connection.close();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, just suggests an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Will this solution be good?

```
    @GetMapping("/login")
public boolean login(@RequestParam String login, @RequestParam String pass, HttpServletRequest request) throws SQLException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    String maxOnline = "0";
    int onlineNow;

    boolean check = usersDao.userExists(login, pass, dataSource.getConnection());
    dataSource.getConnection().close();
    if (check) {
        usersDao.setOnline(session.getId(), login, pass, dataSource.getConnection());
        dataSource.getConnection().close();

        maxOnline = serverPropsDao.getPropValue("max_online", dataSource.getConnection());
        dataSource.getConnection().close();
        onlineNow = usersDao.usersOnline(dataSource.getConnection()).size();
        dataSource.getConnection().close();

        if (Integer.parseInt(maxOnline) < onlineNow)
            serverPropsDao.setPropValue("max_online", String.valueOf(onlineNow), dataSource.getConnection());
        dataSource.getConnection().close();
    }
    return check;
}
```